# Fastlane Testflight from CircleCI

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane, fastlane-pilot

I'm trying to upload a Testflight build whenever tests pass on my develop branch using Fastlane and CircleCI.

Everything goes smoothly until it gets here:

```
Login to App Store Connect (*******************)
The login credentials for '*******************' seem to be wrong
The password was taken from the environment variable
Please make sure it is correct
```

The password I believe comes from the FASTLANE_PASSWORD environment variable that I've entered in Circle's project settings, and the password is an app specific password I created for this purpose.

Running it locally with an app specific password stored in FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD works just fine. Setting that as an env var on Circle has no effect, only FASTLANE_PASSWORD seems to be used.

I tried setting `upload_to_testflight(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)` but no change. Trying to set `apple_id` as well results in an error (apple id shouldn't be defined here).

It reports prior to trying to login that it successfully builds and signs the IPA file. Here's the Fastfile lane:

```
desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
lane :beta do
  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "[project].xcodeproj")
  match(type: "appstore")
  build_app(workspace: "[project].xcworkspace", scheme: "[scheme]")
  upload_to_testflight(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
end
```

Is there a step I'm missing? All the other questions about this seem to be outdated.

Comment: I've not used circle ci so I may not be of any help, but I do the same to upload to testflight with using the app-specific password. You need the apple_id included in the upload_to_testflight command to use the app-specific password though as stated here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/#use-an-application-specific-password-to-upload - so maybe revisit that option and show the error?

Comment: Also, I set FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD in the fastfile itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is that I also needed to provide a FASTLANE_SESSION as well, which I did not do originally. Subject to some hiccups courtesy of Apple, it's now working reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your .env file password IS NOT in quotes.

Make sure it is like this:

```
apple_id_password=pa!@ssword
```

Not like this:

```
apple_id_password="pa!@ssword"
```